# Disabling MAC randomization makes connection to the Internet slower

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have two routers, the main connected to the internet in the living room (Router A),and a second one (Router B) in another room, connected to router A via a LAN cable. Router B has DHCP disabled. This works perfectly and I can access the internet while connecting to Router B. However, if I disable MAC randomization, it does connect my laptop to the network instantly but it takes ~5 to 6 minutes to actually connect to the internet. Enabling MAC randomization does solve this issue but I get a different IP every time I switch from router A to router B. And having a static ip for my laptop is not an option.
How do I resolve this? (i.e how do I switch from Router A to B and vice versa while keeping the same IP?)

P.S connecting to Router A occurs instantly regardless of MAC randomization being enabled or disabled. Also, both routers do not have the same SSID

Comment: How do you disable MAC randomization?

Comment: @harrymc In Windows "Network & internet" > Wi-Fi > [Router B SSID] > Random Hardware Access > off

Comment: How do you switch between routers?

Comment: @harrymc Sometimes my laptop randomly switches to router A, so I have to manually to Router B

Comment: But what action do you do?

Comment: @harrymc win 11 taskbar > manage wifi connections (the arrow besides the wifi tile) > select the other network with the Router B SSID

Comment: Why isn't Router B defined as an access path with the same SSID?

Comment: @harrymc I tried having the same SSID but then devices would _very_ frequently switch like crazy, like even when a device was right next to say router B, it would still switch constantly back and forth when using the same SSID...

Comment: There are strange effects in your network. MAC randomization shouldn't really matter, except if your router has a problem with it. Perhaps updating all firmwares (downloaded only from the manufacturers) might help.